# Looking for GUI layer on top of terminal emulator

Tags: terminal-emulator

Does it exist, a GUI that enhances the command line interface? I see myself constantly doing the same thing like typing out paths, executing the same commands, making the same typos, having to look up how things work it.

Is there a terminal emulator with an interface with configurable buttons/bookmarks? Like I press button A and it writes out a certain path? I understand iTerm2 exists, and it works okay, but still very typing-heavy.

Another example, these terminal interfaces often have very rudimentary (old fashioned) text editors like Vim, requiring to know funky commands to exit (:wqt, are you kidding me!) etc. Why can't such terminal launch a GUI text editor instead?

Comment: [Fig](https://fig.io/) might be of interest to you, it supports GUI autocomplete and shell automation. I'm not sure if it supports custom buttons though, but worth checking out nonetheless.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are looking for. Many of the problems you list can be solved with shell variables and functions. Learning to use the shell properly will propel your productivity to a level which is simply unimaginable with a click-and-drool interface.

Comment: https://warp.dev/ purports to be a reimagined terminal for the modern world, but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you are looking for is called "console file managers", aka "text-based file managers".

There are many versions and variations. Unfortunately, majority was written up to a semi-usable state and forgotten. But we have some gems

*ranger* - for those who loves `vi` and knows its "funky commands" as you put it. But it can do a lot. As for me, the most important command in it is ":q" (remember `vi`?). But it is a real help for vi-lovers!

```
apt install ranger
```

*mc* - Midnight Commander - distant relative of Norton Commander. Very heavy usage of ncurses and therefore is able to work on any terminal. But with a wide spread of `xterm`-able terminals that advantage is diminishing.

```
apt install mc
```

*far2l* - Far Manager - also a distant relative for Norton Commander. Much faster than `mc` and has much more abilities. But it is developed primarily for Windows and Linux version has a limited library of plugins and extensions (comparing to win-version). Also, it is not published in repositories, but compiling yourself is easy.

```
https://github.com/elfmz/far2l
```

And of course there are tons of other managers, just google 'console file manager for linux` and you would get a lot of variations. Some of which are actually GUI mimicking console, like "GNOME Commander", "krusader", "Double Commander", etc. They would give you a file management in graphics, plus a terminal in graphics.